# Concatenate value from 3 excel columns in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

very new to Python here.

I'm triying to concatenate value from 3 columns from an excel sheet into 1 columns.
I do have about 300-400 rows to do

Values are like this

```
COl1   COL 2   COL3
CNMG   432     EMU
TNMG   332     ESU
...
```

Output should be

```
COL3
CNMG432EMU
TNMG332ESU
...
```

I tried about every tutorial in Pandas I could find, but nothing seams to works since I have STR and INT

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is too vague/broad. Do you have a **specific** problem with your program?

Comment: no, I tried about 20 different way and nothing works.

Comment: What does _and nothing works_ mean?

Answer (score 2):

seems like some simple string concatenation should do the trick

```
df['concat'] = df['COL1'] + df['COL 2'].astype(str) + df['COL3']
```

if you have ints, you'll need to cast them as strings, you can check which columns with a simple `print(df.dtypes)`

if you have ints or floats you'll need to use `.astype(str)`

```
print(df)
   COl1  COL2 COL3      concat
0  CNMG   432  EMU  CNMG432EMU
1  TNMG   332  ESU  TNMG332ESU
```

Comment: ah he beat me to it

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fasst reply, I still get an error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\openpyxl-merge.py", line 8, in <module>
    df['concat'] = df['A1'] + df['B1'].astype(str) + df['C1']
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @BenoitDemeule `df` is a standard placeholder name for the DataFrame. It needs to be changed to whatever the DataFrame is called in **your** program.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["COL3"]=df["COL1"]+df["COL2"].astype(str)+df["COL3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this pretty easily in pylightxl https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import pylightxl as xl

db = xl.readxl(‘excelfile.xlsx’)

cat_3_columns = list(zip(db.ws(‘Sheet1’).col(1), db.ws(‘Sheet1’).col(2), db.ws(‘Sheet1’).col(3)))
```